# Symfony2: Dynamic defaults for a custom form type?

Tags: symfony

I use a `entity` form type to provide a list of `Position` entities in a form. I use it often enough (each with the same "setup" code to customize it) that I've decided to make a custom form type from it for better re-use.

Here's the current form type:

```
class PositionType extends AbstractType
{
    private $om;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om, $mode)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        // I need to pass "mode" as an option when building the form.
        $mode = ???
        $query_builder = function (EntityRepository $em) use ($mode) {
            // Limit the positions returned based on the editing mode
            return $em
                ->createQueryBuilder('Position')
                ->orderBy('Position.name')
                ->leftJoin('Position.type', 'Type')
                ->andWhere('Type.id IN (:ids)')
                ->setParameter('ids', Type::typesForMode($mode))
            ;
        };

        $resolver
            ->setRequired(array('mode'))
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'label' => 'Position',
                'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Position',
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => $query_builder,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'position';
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the specifics in the query builder, that doesn't matter. The part that does matter is I'm trying to use a form type option in the query builder.

How can I do this? The problem is I can't use `$mode` (the option I want to pass to alter the query builder) in `setDefaultOptions`.

I was beginning to look for a way to set the query builder from inside `buildForm` but I'm not sure I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy  to achieve. You can build an option that depends on another option.

[OptionResolver Component - Default Values that Depend on another Option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#default-values-that-depend-on-another-option)

Basically you will do:

```
$resolver
    ->setRequired(array('mode', 'em')) // "em" for EntityManager as well
    ->setDefaults(array(
        'label' => 'Position',
        'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Position',
        'property' => 'name',
        #####################################################
        'query_builder' => function(Options $options){
            // Obviously you will need to pass the EntityManager
            $em = $options['em'];

            // Limit the positions returned based on the editing mode
            return $em
                ->createQueryBuilder('Position')
                ->orderBy('Position.name')
                ->leftJoin('Position.type', 'Type')
                ->andWhere('Type.id IN (:ids)')
                ->setParameter('ids', Type::typesForMode($options['mode'])) // 
            ;
        },
        ####################################
        'empty_value' => '',
        'empty_data' => null,
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(),
        ),
    ))
;
```

This is just a rough representation of what `OptionsResolver` can do. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Although, instead of passing the entity manager, I instead just return the callable function as originally done, which gets passed the manager from Symfony

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the form options to pass a variable into the form builder.
For example in controller;

```
public function createAction()
{
    $form = $this->formFactory->create('client', $client, array('name' => 'create'));

    return $this->template->renderResponse('bundle:add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

And in your form type;

```
class PositionType extends AbstractType
{
    private $mode;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->mode = $options['name'];
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        // I need to pass "mode" as an option when building the form.
        $mode = ???
        $query_builder = function (EntityRepository $em) use ($this->mode) {
            // Limit the positions returned based on the editing mode
            return $em
                ->createQueryBuilder('Position')
                ->orderBy('Position.name')
                ->leftJoin('Position.type', 'Type')
                ->andWhere('Type.id IN (:ids)')
                ->setParameter('ids', Type::typesForMode($mode))
            ;
        };

        $resolver
            ->setRequired(array('mode'))
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'label' => 'Position',
                'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Position',
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => $query_builder,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't `setDefaultOptions` get called before `buildForm`?

Comment: @Brian you are correct setDefaultOptions does get called first. Is passing the variable in the constrcutor an option for you?